# Invoke particular method in a webservice when using apache camal and CFX

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-camel

I am using  Apache Camel and CXF  Spring configuration for endpoint How can i invoke a particular method. ie  if the wsdl have defined in 10 methods that I need
to expose 10 cxfEndpoint to the site, or it can be parametrized by the call
somehow? How can  insert 'Method Name' want to invoke in that service ?

```
 <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="serviceEndpoint" address="http://localhost:9000/SoapContext/SoapPort"
        wsdlURL="testutils/hello_world.wsdl"
        serviceClass="org.apache.hello_world_soap_http.Greeter"
        endpointName="s:SoapPort"
        serviceName="s:SOAPService"
    xmlns:s="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So when you create a WSDL with 5 operations these 5 operations will be exposed when you run the WSDL2JAVA tool in CXF.

Lets assume I have a WSDL with 2 operations as follows:

1. GetClient
2. ListClient

In camel when I expose this route as a camel consumer I can see which operation was executed by checking the `headers.operationName` property on the messages.

For example when a user executes the `GetClient` operation the `headers.operationName` will be equal to the string `"GetClient"`.

So I can then create a route such as follows to handle the different operations:

```
    <from uri="cxf:bean:AccountsService?dataFormat=POJO"/>
    <doTry>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${headers.operationName} == 'GetClient'</simple>
                <bean ref="GetClientBean"/>
            </when>
            <when>
                <simple>${headers.operationName} == 'ListClient'</simple>
                <bean ref="ListClientBean"/>
            </when>
            <when>
                <simple>${headers.operationName} == 'SomeOtherOperation'</simple>
                <bean ref="SomeOtherBean"/>
            </when>
        </choice>
```

If you want to limit the operations exposed you can simply throw a exception or construct a error message on the operation that you dont want to expose.

Have fun!